# How many sajdas are in Qur'an?

Tags: quran-recitation, sajda, sajdat-al-tilaawah

I would like to know the number of sajdas in Qur'an, and the exact verse numbers where performing a `Sajda` is required.

Just mentioning the verses' numbers would be sufficient instead of referencing complete Ayat here, as it would become obligatory for the person reading the answer (you know what I mean) which may be inconvenient for some people.

-Jazakallah.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are 15 sajdas in Quran, as comes in this Hadith:

> Narrated Amr ibn al-'As: The Prophet () taught me fifteen prostrations
>   while reciting the Qur'an, including three in al-Mufassal and two in
>   Surah al-Hajj. Abu Dawud said: Abu al-Darda' has reported eleven
>   prostrations from the Prophet (), but chain of this tradition is weak.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَبْدِ الرَّحِيمِ بْنِ الْبَرْقِيِّ،
>   حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ أَبِي مَرْيَمَ، أَخْبَرَنَا نَافِعُ بْنُ يَزِيدَ،
>   عَنِ الْحَارِثِ بْنِ سَعِيدٍ الْعُتَقِيِّ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ
>   مُنَيْنٍ، - مِنْ بَنِي عَبْدِ كُلاَلٍ - عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ الْعَاصِ،
>   أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم أَقْرَأَهُ خَمْسَ عَشْرَةَ
>   سَجْدَةً فِي الْقُرْآنِ مِنْهَا ثَلاَثٌ فِي الْمُفَصَّلِ وَفِي سُورَةِ
>   الْحَجِّ سَجْدَتَانِ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو دَاوُدَ رُوِيَ عَنْ أَبِي
>   الدَّرْدَاءِ عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم إِحْدَى عَشْرَةَ
>   سَجْدَةً وَإِسْنَادُهُ وَاهٍ ‏.‏
>
> [Sunan Abu Dawud](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/7/1)

They are in the following Ayat(in order):

- [Al-'A`rāf:206](http://quran.com/7/206)
- [Ar-Ra`d:15](http://quran.com/13/15)
- [An-Naĥl:49](http://quran.com/16/49), but the sajda should be performed after reading the ayah [#50](http://quran.com/16/50)  (when the sujood meaning is complete).
- [Al-'Isrā':107](http://quran.com/17/107), but the sajda should be performed after reading the ayah [#109](http://quran.com/17/109) (when the sujood meaning is complete).
- [Maryam:58](http://quran.com/19/58)
- [Al-Ĥaj:18](http://quran.com/22/18)
- [Al-Ĥaj:77](http://quran.com/22/77)
- [Al-Furqān:60](http://quran.com/25/60)
- [An-Naml:25](http://quran.com/27/25), but the sajda should be performed after reading the ayah [#26](http://quran.com/27/26) (when the sujood meaning is complete).
- [As-Sajdah:15](http://quran.com/32/15)
- [Şād:24](http://quran.com/38/24)
- [Fuşşilat:37](http://quran.com/41/37), but the sajda should be performed after reading the ayah [#38](http://quran.com/41/38) (when the sujood meaning is complete).
- [An-Najm:62](http://quran.com/53/62)
- [Al-'Inshiqāq:21](http://quran.com/84/21)
- [Al-`Alaq:19](http://quran.com/96/19)

Also note that performing the **sajdah is not obligatory but is a stressed (confirmed) sunnah** (سنة مؤكدة) that is highly recommended to follow. Here is a hadith:

> Narrated Rabi'a: 'Umar bin Al-Khattab recited Surat-an-Nahl on a
>   Friday on the pulpit and when he reached the verse of Sajda he got
>   down from the pulpit and prostrated and the people also prostrated.
>   The next Friday 'Umar bin Al-Khattab recited the same Sura and when he
>   reached the verse of Sajda he said, "O people! When we recite the
>   verses of Sajda (during the sermon) whoever prostrates does the right
>   thing, yet it is no sin for the one who does not prostrate." And 'Umar
>   did not prostrate (that day). Added Ibn `Umar "Allah has not made the
>   prostration of recitation compulsory but if we wish we can do it."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا إِبْرَاهِيمُ بْنُ مُوسَى، قَالَ أَخْبَرَنَا هِشَامُ بْنُ
>   يُوسُفَ، أَنَّ ابْنَ جُرَيْجٍ، أَخْبَرَهُمْ قَالَ أَخْبَرَنِي أَبُو
>   بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي مُلَيْكَةَ، عَنْ عُثْمَانَ بْنِ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ
>   التَّيْمِيِّ، عَنْ رَبِيعَةَ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ الْهُدَيْرِ
>   التَّيْمِيِّ ـ قَالَ أَبُو بَكْرٍ وَكَانَ رَبِيعَةُ مِنْ خِيَارِ
>   النَّاسِ عَمَّا حَضَرَ رَبِيعَةُ مِنْ عُمَرَ بْنِ الْخَطَّابِ ـ رضى
>   الله عنه ـ قَرَأَ يَوْمَ الْجُمُعَةِ عَلَى الْمِنْبَرِ بِسُورَةِ
>   النَّحْلِ حَتَّى إِذَا جَاءَ السَّجْدَةَ نَزَلَ فَسَجَدَ وَسَجَدَ
>   النَّاسُ، حَتَّى إِذَا كَانَتِ الْجُمُعَةُ الْقَابِلَةُ قَرَأَ بِهَا
>   حَتَّى إِذَا جَاءَ السَّجْدَةَ قَالَ يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنَّا
>   نَمُرُّ بِالسُّجُودِ فَمَنْ سَجَدَ فَقَدْ أَصَابَ، وَمَنْ لَمْ
>   يَسْجُدْ فَلاَ إِثْمَ عَلَيْهِ‏.‏ وَلَمْ يَسْجُدْ عُمَرُ ـ رضى الله
>   عنه‏.‏ وَزَادَ نَافِعٌ عَنِ ابْنِ عُمَرَ ـ رضى الله عنهما إِنَّ
>   اللَّهَ لَمْ يَفْرِضِ السُّجُودَ إِلاَّ أَنْ نَشَاءَ‏.‏
>
> [[Sahih Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/17/11)

Also here is a hadith about how good performing sajdah is:

> It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that when, the son of
>   Adam recites the Ayat of Sajdah (prostration) and then falls down in
>   prostration, the Satan goes into seclusion and weeps and says: Alas,
>   and in the narration of Abu Kuraib the words are: Woe unto me, the son
>   of Adam was commanded to prostrate, and he prostrated and Paradise was
>   entitled to him and I was commanded to prostrate, but I refused and am
>   doomed to Hell.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ، وَأَبُو كُرَيْبٍ قَالاَ
>   حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو مُعَاوِيَةَ، عَنِ الأَعْمَشِ، عَنْ أَبِي صَالِحٍ،
>   عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم
>   ‏ "‏ إِذَا قَرَأَ ابْنُ آدَمَ السَّجْدَةَ فَسَجَدَ اعْتَزَلَ
>   الشَّيْطَانُ يَبْكِي يَقُولُ يَا وَيْلَهُ - وَفِي رِوَايَةِ أَبِي
>   كُرَيْبٍ يَا وَيْلِي - أُمِرَ ابْنُ آدَمَ بِالسُّجُودِ فَسَجَدَ فَلَهُ
>   الْجَنَّةُ وَأُمِرْتُ بِالسُّجُودِ فَأَبَيْتُ فَلِيَ النَّارُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏

[[Sahih Muslim]](http://sunnah.com/urn/302540)

Hope that's clarifying and helpful.

Answer (score 5):

1. [Araf 206](http://quran.com/7/206)
2. [Rad 15](http://quran.com/13/15)
3. [Nahl 49](http://quran.com/16/49)
4. [Isra 107](http://quran.com/17/107)
5. [Maryam 58](http://quran.com/19/59)
6. [Hajj 18](http://quran.com/22/18)
7. [Furqan 60](http://quran.com/25/60)
8. [Naml 25](http://quran.com/27/25)
9. [Sajda 15](http://quran.com//32/15)
10. [Sad 24](http://quran.com/38/24)
11. [Fussilat 37](http://quran.com/41/37)
12. [Nejm 62](http://quran.com/53/62)
13. [Inshiqaq 21](http://quran.com/84/21)
14. [Alaq 19](http://quran.com/96/19)